# window.location.hash - stop reload in chrome

Tags: jquery, hash, location, reload, scrollto

I have the following problem:

```
$('.gotoservices').click(function(){
    $('html,body').scrollTo($("#services"),1000);
    window.location.hash = "services";
    return false;
});
```

This code works but for some reason the page flashes before the `scrollTo`.

If I remove the `window.location.hash` line the `return false;` works and the page doesn't flash/flicker.

I have tried `e.preventDefault` - doesn't work

I'm struggling to find any work around.

Cheers

Comment: I think you only need one of them. Setting `window.location.hash` will also scroll to the location.

Comment: @minitech that's incorrect in Chrome's case

Comment: @Pierre: Er... [no, it's not?](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/TBAce/)

Comment: @minitech: my bad for typing before thinking. The use case in which this doesn't work in chrome is when you set the `window.location.hash` and then `window.location.reload()` the page. When a page is reloaded, Chrome seems to prioritize the previous scroll position over what window.location.hash is pointing at (which is not the case in FireFox)

Answer (score 2):

In a generic sense, you can update the URL with HTML5 `history` without the browser re-rendering anything:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');
```

Of course, you will likely want to have fallbacks for older browsers, and you might want to do this only after your animation is done.

So, integrated with your code:

```
$('.gotoservices').click(function(e){
    //Prevent default so the browser doesn't try to do anything
    e.preventDefault();
    var $hash = "#services";
    $('html,body').scrollTo($($hash), 1000, function () {
        //If the browser supports HTML5 history,
        //use that to update the hash in the URL
        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, $hash);
        }
        //Else use the old-fashioned method to do the same thing,
        //albeit with a flicker of content
        else {
            location.hash = $hash;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a function that specifically scrolls to #services?  You're telling your web browser to go to #services and then to scroll to #services.  Probably has a conflict with that.  If you're trying to update the url to have the hash, then you probably need

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So that it doesn't try to "go to the hash".

Comment: Thanks - there is no anchor tag called #services its the jquery ref to the layer - the hash is purely there to store state.

Comment: this does still load the page.